# struggling on getting XML from database to show on the form on a table or grid

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, linq

I have been truing to retrieve XML data that I have stored in an XML field in sql server and now i need to show information in a webpage/form as to give the user information about the stored report xml data, the following is my attempt and it throws a index 0 exception

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Xml;
using System.Data;
using System.Xml.Linq;

public partial class Default2 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
        SqlConnection cnn = null;
        SqlCommand cmd = null;



        try
        {
            cnn = new SqlConnection();
            cnn.ConnectionString = "ICDBConnectionString";
            cnn.Open();

            string selectQry = "WITH XMLNamespaces('TUReport' AS Debtor) SELECT* FROM TUReport WHERE ConsumerID = @ID FOR XML RAW('TUReport');";
            cmd = new SqlCommand(selectQry, cnn);
            int ID = Convert.ToInt32(txtIDNumber.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", ID);

            DataSet dataset = new DataSet();

            //System.IO.StringReader xmlSR = new System.IO.StringReader(cmd)

            XmlReader reader = cmd.ExecuteXmlReader();

            dataset.ReadXml(reader, XmlReadMode.ReadSchema);

            results.DataSource = reader;
            results.DataBind();
            cnn.Close();


            //if (reader.Read())

            //    xdoc.Load(reader);


        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }

        finally
        {
            cmd.Dispose();
            cnn.Close();
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a space missing in the SQL between 'Select' and '*'. (Select* FROM TUReport)

Comment: catch statement throws me this error still.. An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in App_Web_1nvanvoq.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0.

Comment: which line is throwing the exception? Is ConsumerID in TUReport a varchar?

Comment: Changed the string to int and still i get the same error when i debug the program